# i am trying to fetch data from my mongodb Database with django but keep getting : the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not OrderedDict

Tags: django, mongodb, django-rest-framework, djongo

so i have an employes collection with a bunch of data that is in this format :

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "511d0a9f181b16509ae5f7dd"
  },
  "nom": "Leberre",
  "prenom": "Stephanie",
  "anciennete": 1,
  "adresse": {
    "numero": 79,
    "codepostal": 9500,
    "ville": "Toulouse",
    "rue": "Jean Moulin"
  },
  "tel": 559608352,
  "prime": 1500
},
```

here is the models.py :

```
from django.db import models

class Employee(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    prenom = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    anciennete = models.IntegerField()
    adresse = models.JSONField()
    tel = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    prime = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.nom}, {self.prenom}"
```

serializers.py :

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Employee

class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = '__all__'
```

and finally views.py :

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import generics
from .models import Employee
from .serializers import EmployeeSerializer

class EmployeeListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Employee.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EmployeeSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        
        serializer = self.get_serializer(self.get_queryset(), many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

i keep getting :"the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not OrderedDict
". i dont need a very specific solution, just any solution works even if it involves modifying all the files mentioned above

//edit

here is the settings.py file :

```
    from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-_v8lmb3--wwr@2e(4waw2636grijurf+i()(t*+eqv!bug%zqo'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'EmployeeApp'
]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000"
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'employes.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'employes.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'employes',
        
    }
}



# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

and here is the full traceback :

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/employes/?format=json

Django Version: 4.1.13
Python Version: 3.11.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'corsheaders',
 'EmployeeApp']
Installed Middleware:
['corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/brahimkhalilkhalef/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 56, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/brahimkhalilkhalef/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/brahimkhalilkhalef/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 55, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/brahimkhalilkhalef/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 103, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/brahimkhalilkhalef/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/brahimkhalilkhalef/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/brahimkhalilkhalef/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/Users/brahimkhalilkhalef/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/brahimkhalilkhalef/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 199, in get
    return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/brahimkhalilkhalef/employes/EmployeeApp/views.py", line 13, in list
    return Response(serializer.data)
  File "/Users/brahimkhalilkhalef/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 768, in data
    ret = super().data
  File "/Users/brahimkhalilkhalef/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 253, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "/Users/brahimkhalilkhalef/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 686, in to_representation
    return [
  File "/Users/brahimkhalilkhalef/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 394, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/Users/brahimkhalilkhalef/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1867, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/Users/brahimkhalilkhalef/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 117, in __iter__
    for row in compiler.results_iter(results):
  File "/Users/brahimkhalilkhalef/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1336, in apply_converters
    value = converter(value, expression, connection)
  File "/Users/brahimkhalilkhalef/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/json.py", line 86, in from_db_value
    return json.loads(value, cls=self.decoder)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '

Exception Type: TypeError at /api/employes/
Exception Value: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not OrderedDict
```

Comment: Please share the *full* traceback.

Comment: How do you let Django talk with MongoDB, can you share the settings you use?

Answer (score 0):

You need to serialize the address field separately

```
class AddressSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    numero = serializers.IntegerField()
    codepostal = serializers.IntegerField()
    ville = serializers.CharField()
    rue = serializers.CharField()
```

Try adding this class to serialize the address json and then call this inside the EmployeeSerializer